# getting too many re-renders in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, rendering

I have a React component named **`Search`** where I'm iterating over data items and rendering a **`SearchCard`** component for each item. The **`SearchCard`** component contains logic for handling play and pause actions. I've noticed that the console log in the **`SearchCard`** component is being triggered multiple times, and there are also multiple fetch requests being made.

```
// SearchCard.jsx
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PlayPause from "./PlayPause";
import { playPause, setActiveSong } from "../redux/features/playerSlice";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const SearchCard = ({ song, i, isPlaying, activeSong, data }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log('heyyy!'); // This log statement is appearing multiple times

  const handlePauseClick = () => {
    dispatch(playPause(false));
  };

  const handlePlayClick = () => {
    dispatch(setActiveSong({ data, song, i }));
    dispatch(playPause(true));
  };

  // ... rest of the component

  return (
    // ... component JSX
  );
};

export default SearchCard;
```

```
// Search.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Error, Loader, SearchCard } from '../components';
import { useGetSongsBySearchQuery } from '../redux/services/shazam';

const Search = () => {
  const { searchTerm } = useParams();
  const { activeSong, isPlaying } = useSelector((state) => state.player);
  const { data, isFetching, error } = useGetSongsBySearchQuery(searchTerm);

  const songs = data?.tracks?.map((song) => song.data);

  if (isFetching) return <Loader title={`Searching ${searchTerm}...`} />;

  if (error) return <Error />;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <h2 className="font-bold text-3xl text-white text-left mt-4 mb-10">
        Showing results for <span className="font-black">{searchTerm}</span>
      </h2>

      <div className="flex flex-wrap sm:justify-start justify-center gap-8">
        {songs.map((song, i) => (
          <SearchCard
            key={song.id}
            song={song}
            isPlaying={isPlaying}
            activeSong={activeSong}
            data={data.tracks}
            i={i}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

**Expected Behavior:** I expect the **`SearchCard`** component to log only once and fetch data once per rendered instance. However, it seems to be logging and fetching data multiple times, leading to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check useEffect Dependencies:
   In the SearchCard.jsx component, look at the useEffect hook (which is currently not shown in your provided code) and ensure that you've listed all the dependencies that the useEffect relies on. If any dependency is missing, it could lead to unexpected behavior.

2.Optimize Render and Avoid Side Effects:
You can use React.memo to memoize your SearchCard component and prevent it from re-rendering if the props haven't changed. However, keep in mind that memoization is a trade-off, and it might not be suitable for all scenarios.

3. Fetch Data in the Parent Component:
   Consider moving the data fetching logic to the parent component (Search.jsx in this case) and passing the necessary data as props to the SearchCard component. This can help to centralize data fetching and avoid unnecessary fetch calls.
4. Debugging:
   If the issue persists, you may want to use browser developer tools to inspect the React component tree and check which components are rendering and causing the additional renders. This can help you identify the root cause of the unexpected behavior.